# Cordova Netbeans Install plugin from plugin.properties since old format has been deprecated

Tags: cordova, netbeans, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I'm using netbeans and i build my cordova app directly from netbeans to my phone.
I used to install plugins by using the file **plugin.properties**
ex : org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser=https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
I wanted to update the plugin, so i deleted it and tryed to reinstall it.
Unfortunately it won't reinstall...
I get : Fetching plugin "cordova-plugin-compat" via plugin registry
Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-geolocation':Error: Failed to fetch package information for cordova-plugin-compat
Is it due to the **deprecation of plugin nomenclatures** ?
how can i do ?
I also tryed org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser=https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation.git

Answer (score 0):

I use NetBeans when developing Cordova/Ionic apps and I can tell you that there are problems with plugin managment and build time in case of NetBeans. When there are some problems with plugins, use CLI. Try to remove plugin with command: `cordova plugin rm <plugin> --save`. There are many entries for plugins in config files across cordova projects (config.xml, fetch.json, android.json ...). You can easily check if you have old plugin entry written somewhere: remove platform and add it again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'm on windows and i've never managed to install cordova properly. Last time i tryed successfully i had to delete it and reinstall netbeans because it didn't find java or android sdk any more. I'd rather find a solution using only netbeans if possible.

Comment: Using cordova CLI isn't bound to operating system. Just run cmd.exe or node.js command line and type cordova commands. If `cordova` isn't visible as command in cmd, try to install it by downloading and installing node.js, then typing `npm install -g cordova` in node cmd. If you have any problems just look here: https://cordova.apache.org/#getstarted